# connect line between two boxes avoiding passing others

Tags: graphics, line

I have several boxes (x,y,width,height) randomly scattered around, and some of them need to be linked from point (x1,y1) in box1 to point (x2,y2) in box2 by drawing a line.

I am trying to figure a way to make such line avoid passing through any other boxes (other than box1 and box2) by drawing several straight interconnected lines to go around any box in the way (if it is not possible to go with one straight line).

The problem is that I don't know an algorithm for such thing (let alone having a technical/common name for it). Would appreciate any help in the form of algorithm or expressed ideas.

Comment: You can cheat. If you draw the two origin boxes and the line first and then draw the random boxes afterwards (with the same stroke style as the line), it will look as if the line just outlines the boxes instead of intersecting them.

Comment: it's not really clear what you want to do..lines are given or do you have to choose which line to draw? because if they're given there's no way to avoid overlapping if the do overlap a box

Comment: maybe i get it...does the line not to be necessarly a single segment but they can be obtained joining more than one segment?

Comment: @PhpMyCoder, haha, nice idea and I like your way of thinking. But it is not good for my situation, there might be several lines going around that box and I cannot just fake them all together (they will look merged) :)

Comment: @Simone: a line from (x1,y1) to (x2,y2) relative to box1 and box2, and you can go around anything in the way as long as you start from (x1,y1) and arrive at (x2,y2) using a single line, or several straight interconnected lines (if needed).

Comment: @ccit the lines can't be diagonal right?

Comment: well, I would prefer the ability to choose (horizontal/vertical-only or diagonal), but a solution with one of the two would be acceptable.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. Put all *(x,y)* coords of the corners of the boxes in a set *V*
2. Add the start- and end coordinates to *V*.
3. Create a set of edges *E* connecting each corner that does not cross any box-side (except for the diagonals in the boxes).

   How to check if a line crosses a box side can be done with [this algorithm](http://paulbourke.net/geometry/lineline2d/)
4. Now use a path-finding algorithm of your choice, to find a path in the graph *(V, E)*.

   If you need a simple algorithm that finds the shortest path, just go with a BFS.

(This will produce a path that goes along the sides of some boxes. If this is undesirable, you could in step 1 put the points at some distance delta from the actual corners.)

---

If the edges may not be diagonal:

1. Create a large *grid* of lines that goes between the boxes.
2. Throw away the grid-edges that cross a box-side.
3. Find a path in the grid using a path-finding algorithm of your choice.

Comment: The algorithm is great, but can you explain step 3 in more details. Do I create edges from all the coords (including start/end) as long as they don't intersect any box side? Also is it possible to modify such algorithm to only generate vertical and horizontal lines (and not diagonals) if desired?

Comment: Yes, if the line between start / end doesn't cross any box-sides, the you would definitely want to include that edge... that edge will actually be the resulting path! Regarding your second concern, I'm not sure. However you solve it, you will probably use a path-finding algorithm in the end (A*, BFS, Dijkstra,...) so you probably need to set up some graph in either case.

Comment: I liked the first algorithm because it was efficient, and with some distance delta (to avoid touching edges) it might be the most proper solution. Of course I must have a graph (and path-finding algorithm) in the end, but I wanted a graph with minimum vertices. Your answer satisfies this. I might use the first one first, then adjust the diagonal lines by taking them in a small grid. Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming that the lines can't be diagonal, here's one simple way. It's based on BFS and will also find the shortest line connecting the points:

Just create a graph, containing one vertex for each point (x, y) and for each point the edges:

```
((x,y),(x+1,y))    ((x,y),(x-1,y))     ((x,y),(x,y+1))     ((x,y),(x,y-1))
```

But each of this edges must be present only if it doesn't overlap a box.

Now just do a plain BFS from point (x1,y1) to (x2,y2)

It's really easy to obtain also diagonal lines the same way but you will need 8 edges for each vertex, that are, in addition to the previouses 4:

```
((x,y),(x-1,y+1))    ((x,y),(x-1,y-1))     ((x,y),(x+1,y-1))     ((x,y),(x+1,y+1))
```

Still, each edge must be present only if it doesn't overlap a box.

EDIT

If you can't consider space divided into a grid, here's another possibility, it won't give you the very shortest path, though.

Create a graph, in which each box is a vertex and has an edge to any other box that can be reached without the line to overlap a third box. Now find the shortet path using dijkstra between box1 and box2 containing the two points.

Now consider each box to have a small countour that doesn't overlap any other box. This way you can link the entering and the exiting point of each box in the path found through dijistra, passing through the countour.

Comment: when you say "vertex for each point (x,y)" do I understand that you divide the space into grid?

Comment: in fact you can always divide space into pixels, if what you need is a algorithm for pratical use. it's a lot more faster to divide space into pixels; it also will allow you to check overlapping of a point and a box in constant time, using an auxiliary boolean grid

Comment: Nice and simple solution. But I am concerned about the complexity (space/time) when you deal with it as pixels (also with large space or narrow grid row/column). Also, I will end up with a line touching a box edge when using pixels as grid (so a grid with proper spacing is preferred).

Comment: yes you're right about that, you can't simply use the pixels as a grid; however the complexity would be linear in the number of grid points. Give also a look to the second solution i gave; it's a little more approximated but it should give you a good result

Comment: Your answer is detailed and correct, but while it will solve the problem, it will not be the most efficient. If I didn't get "aioobe" answer, I would have surely chosen yours. Thank you for your time and effort.

Comment: you're welcome..but i still think that the second solution i gave you it's really efficient as it not depends on a grid and it only depends on boxes number...however you could always give me a +1 ;D

Comment: If I could I would surely do (as you deserve it), unfortunately I cannot (technically) up-vote :(

Comment: don't worry! however i still think you should have choosen my second solution ;)

Comment: just got the privilege to up-vote, and I up-voted you now as promised :)